# I need to add stripe processing to customer during checkout session. How it to be added

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, stripe-payments

```
 const price = await this.stripeClient.prices.create({
        unit_amount: Math.round(createCheckOutSessionDto?.amount * 100),
        currency: 'gbp',

        product: 'prod_OgNbjDxP7OVnrl',
      });
      const response = await this.stripeClient.checkout.sessions.create({
        
        customer: stripeId || customer,

        payment_method_types: ['paypal', 'card'],
        line_items: [
          {
            price: price.id,
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        metadata: {
          paymentId: createPaymentDetail?.id,
          customerId: stripeId || customer,
          userId: authUser?.userId,
          bidId: serviceRequestDto?.serviceRequestId,
        },
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${environment?.successUrl}?serviceRequestId=${serviceRequestDto?.serviceRequestId}`,
        cancel_url: environment?.cancelUrl,
      });
```

How to add the stripe processing fee to the customer.

I need to add the stripe processing fee to the customer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Stripe fees on to customers by including them in the final charge amount. You can refer to this [doc](https://support.stripe.com/questions/passing-the-stripe-fee-on-to-customers) on how to calculate the final amount.